# Mapping async parallel requests to their IDs

Tags: javascript, ajax, async-await, axios

So I need to fetch data concurrently from multiple sources, and my code looks something like this:

```
myArray = [
    {
        id: 987447,
        url: http://someurl.com/data1.json
    },
    {
        id: 923473,
        url: http://someurl.com/data2.json
    },
]

async function getData(myArray) {
    let data = await Promise.all(
        myArray.map(a => axios.get(a.url))
    )
    // console.log(data);
}
```

.. however, the issue is that once the data is fetched, it doesn't have any link with the IDs in `myArray` so I don't know which object belongs to which `id`. How do I tie the returned data to the array element the request was initiated from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all` returned data are in the same order than the `Promises` you gave to it.

```js
const arr = [{
  url: 'URLA',
}, {
  url: 'URLB',
}, {
  url: 'URLC',
}];

async function funcAsync(url) {
  return url;
}

(async() => {
  const ret = await Promise.all(arr.map(x => funcAsync(x.url)));

  console.log(ret);
})();
```

---

If you want to make the correspondence between the returned data and the original array, you can use the position of the data, like :

```js
const arr = [{
  url: 'URLA',
}, {
  url: 'URLB',
}, {
  url: 'URLC',
}];

async function funcAsync(url) {
  return url;
}

(async() => {
  const ret = await Promise.all(arr.map(x => funcAsync(x.url)));

  const correspondance = ret.map((x, xi) => ({
    ...arr[xi],

    result: x,
  }));

  console.log(correspondance);
})();
```